# Python 3D Dataframe: Sort Values by To Columns and get the mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, mean

I searched for a solution on stackoverflow for a while now and havent got any solution yet. So hopefully you can help me out:

I have a dataframe with 3 columns ['Attrition', 'JobRole', 'MonthlyIncome']

I sorted the dataframe by its different values for Attrition (YES/NO) and its different JobRoles and wanna get the mean of the MonthlyIncome

e.g for Attrition==Yes & JobRole=='Healthcare' -> 'MonthlyIncome'=x

```
avg_inc=df[['Attrition', 'MonthlyIncome', 'JobRole']].sort_values(['Attrition', 'JobRole'])
'''




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cvYy.png


I hope anyone can help me out. Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want something like/
Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Attrition':['No','No','No','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes'],'MonthlyIncome':[34567,7890,11234,56789,67890,65345,45782,97802], 'JobRole':['NS','DR','HD','DR','NS','HR','NS','HR']})
```

Groupby and calculate mean

```
df['Mean_MonthlyIncome']=df.groupby(['JobRole','Attrition'])['MonthlyIncome'].transform('mean')
```

Or

```
df.groupby(['JobRole','Attrition'])['MonthlyIncome'].mean()
```

Comment: How do you want the dataframe to look/ See if we can help

Comment: Thanks you already helped me out. I tried to work with the groupby function but always got a new dataframe with 0 entries. As soon as I added the .mean() it worked. Can you explain why?